# How to use getElementById with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, dom, cookies

In a php file, there is a textbox with name `"User"`.

I've used cookie to save the `user`.

However, how can I do something like this?

```
$user = $_COOKIE['user'];
document.getElementById('User').value = '$user';
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is duplicate? It is __OUTSIDE__ the js code, you know?

Comment: Hey, is it `exact duplicate`?

Comment: Have you actually read the answers? If you did, did you fully understand the concept?

Comment: I am asking about how to use document.getelementbyid in this question and the result is `no` in php. The answer is related to the may-be-duplicate question. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to teach you a fundamental concept. Read the whole thing and you will get wiser. PS: in the answer there's something like this mentioned `var baz = <?php echo 42; ?>;` which is almost the same what John Conde did. The only difference: the duplicate I linked will give you an in-depth explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [access cookie values directly in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie). But to make your code workable, you just need to use PHP tags and an echo statement:

```
document.getElementById('User').value = '<?php echo $user; ?>';
```

Or if you're using PHP 5.4+ or have short echo tags enabled:

```
document.getElementById('User').value = '<?= $user; ?>';
```

Comment: smart! why haven't i thought of that?

Comment: Are you sure `$user` has a value?

Comment: No,No,No. It worked like a charm! Sorry for my rudeness.

Comment: And I really have to accept your answer after 4 minutes. _You can accept an answer in 4 minutes._

Comment: And this is my result : http://jamie-is-cool.comeze.com/chat.php

Comment: Nice. Good luck with it. :)